# The GET method is not supported for route post_wishlist. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, get

I am adding a route in my Laravel application for an "add to wishlist" feature, but I am getting "method not supported" when I try to use it.

I have added an anchor tag and defined its route in the href:

```
<a href="{{url('/post_wishlist')}}" id="addtowishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x addtowishliststyle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:' + (cardimg['inWishlist'] ? '#8B0000' : 'white') + '"></i></a>
```

I have also created a route in the web.php file:

```
Route::post('/post_wishlist', [MyCartController::class, 'post_wishlist'])->name('post_wishlist');

public function post_wishlist()
{
    echo "add to wishlist called";
}
```

When clicking the link I get the following error:

> The GET method is not supported for route post_wishlist. Supported methods: POST

Is there an issue with the anchor tag?

Comment: That `style=...` definition looks odd

Answer (score 1):

Clicking a `<a href` tag always causes the browser to generate a HTTP GET request. But with `Route::post` you defined your route as only accepting HTTP POST requests.

To resolve it you can either:

- redefine the route to accept GET, or
- replace the anchor tag with a form and a button which can generate a POST request.

And as a background task, make sure you understand what HTTP methods are. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead `Route::get` and `<a href="{{route('post_wishlist')}}">`

If you want to store data use Post ex.

```
    Route::post('/post_wishlist', [MyCartController::class, 'post_wishlist'])->name('post_wishlist');
    
    
    <form action="{{route('post_wishlist')}}" method="POST">
     @csrf
```